# Ubuntu 20.04 CIS xccdf benchmarks

Tags: openscap

I was hoping that someone knew where to find xccdf files for Ubuntu 20.04 with CIS benchmarks to run with Openscap. It looks like the out-of-the-box Openscap only includes RHEL, firefox, and java. I see that Ubuntu Security Guide might be an option, but I'm looking for something free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the OpenSCAP project GitHub repository:
[https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/tree/master/](https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/tree/master)

I think also the official CIS website (https://www.cisecurity.org/) provides XCCDF files for various operating systems, including Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I don't see xccdfs for Ubuntu 20.04 through the git project, nor through the CIS website.  Benchmarks are available, but not xccdf files.

Comment: @sam Try going to releases and downloading the latest release.

Comment: @idontknow, thanks! ansible remediation playbook under release is ultimately what I wanted.